# Why am I getting the error "not all code paths return a value" for this bool method

Tags: c#, class, methods, boolean

I am trying to create a class method that checks a list named 'IngredientList' to see if it contains citrus items. I think it has to do with the else statement 'return false'. This is a portion of my code.

```
         public bool CheckIfCitrus()
        {
            foreach (string ing in IngredientList)
            {
                if ((ing.ToLower() == "lime peel") | (ing.ToLower() == "orange peel"))
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: because you only return inside your loop. _what happens if `IngredientList` is empty_? think of that, and you have the answer.

Comment: Also, if the IngredientList contains "chocolate" as first item and "lime peel" as second it will return false which is probably not what you intended.

Answer (score 2):

```
public bool CheckIfCitrus()
    {
        foreach (string ing in IngredientList)
        {
            if ((ing.ToLower() == "lime peel") | (ing.ToLower() == "orange peel"))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        
        return false;
    }
```

You have to return something in all cases.

Setting a default like this works.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the issue.

You handled all if conditions. But inside a `for each` loop.
You will enter the loop only if **IngredientList** has atleast 1 entry